# Demonstrating the effect of aliasing

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, sampling, aliasing

How does the signal look when we don't use the Nyquist rate to remove aliasing from a signal during sampling?

Let's suppose the signal is sinusoidal, with a frequency of 500 Hz and an amplitude of 2.

```
signal = 2*cos(2*pi*500*t)
```

If I sample it, (replacing t=nTs , Ts = sampling period and n represent number of samples) and plotting the sampled signals with a different sampling period using the subplot command in MATLAB, how could I identify the aliasing in a sampled signal?

Here is the example code that plotted two signals, one at the Nyquist rate while the other less than the Nyquist rate:

```
A = 2;
Fmax = 10;
Fs = 2*Fmax;
n = 0:1/Fs:1;
Cont = A*sin(2*pi*(Fmax/Fs)*n);
Cont1 = A*sin(2*pi*(Fmax/18)*n);
subplot(2,1,1)
stem(n,Cont)
hold on
stem(n,Cont1)
```

and here is the waveform:

[image]

I wasn't able to identify the aliasing. How did it affect the signal when Nyquist rate didn't use?

Comment: Due to an error, your example was not, in fact, sampling at below half the frequency of your test signal.  Try sampling a 1 MHz signal at 1 Hz.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mODqQvlrgIQ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't identify aliasing with a simple sinusoid at a specific frequency and that in a way is the whole point about trying to avoid it. You can't know if the sinusoid you are "looking at" is $Q$ Hz or $2Fs-Q$Hz.

A single aliased sinusoidal component looks just like a non-aliased sinusoid. If you want to experience aliasing, you have to attempt it with either a more complex waveform or a sinusoid that is changing in time.

One way to "experience aliasing" is to undersample a [chirp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp) in the following way:

```
Fs = 8000;t=0:(1./Fs):(5-1./Fs);p=2.*pi.*t; %Sampling Frequency, Time Vector, Phase Vector
y1 = chirp(t,0,5,Fs/2.0); %Create a chirp that goes from DC to Fs/2.0
spectrogram(y1); %Have a look at it through spectrogram, please pay attention at the axis labels. This is basically going to be a "line" increasing with time.
soundsc(y1,Fs); %Listen to it...It clearly "goes up" in frequency
y2 = chirp(t,0,5,Fs); %Now create a chirp that goes from DC to Fs
spectrogram(y2); %Have a look at it through spectrogram
soundsc(y2,Fs); %Listen to it...Do you "get" the folding of the spectrum?
```

In general, you can think of Sampling as [Modulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation) because this is what is effectively happening at the [sample and hold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold) element of an ADC converter.

This will enable you to understand more easily concepts like [undersampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undersampling) for example (and applications where it is perfectly OK to sample at lower than the Nyquist rates). But also, you can load a WAV file in MATLAB (with 'wavread') containing some more complex signal and prior to listening to it with 'soundsc', simply multiply it with a "square" wave* (you might want to lookup function 'square') at some frequency lower than the WAV file's $F_s$. This will effectively introduce the key (unwanted) characteristic of aliasing which is this [folding of the spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Folding). The result is not very pleasant so you might want to keep your speakers volume down.

I hope this helps.

*EDIT: Obviously, "square" returns a square with an amplitude in the interval [-1,1] so prior to multiplying it with your signal it would be better to rescale it as:

```
aSquareWave = (square(100.*p)+1.0)/2.0 % Where p is the phase vector and here we are producing a square wave at 100Hz (given an Fs of 8kHz as above). aSquareWave's amplitude is now in the interval [0,1]
```

Answer (score 6):

You have the right idea, but a key mistake was messing up your results.

```
n=0:1/Fs:1;
```

By making the time increments 1/Fs you are implicitly making the time units seconds.  In other words, "0" is 0 seconds, and "1" is 1 second.

```
Cont = A*sin(2*pi*(Fmax/Fs)*n);
```

By normalizing the sinusoid frequency by Fs you are implicitly assuming that the sample unit is 1/Fs seconds.  That is why you were getting lots of samples for a single sinusoid cycle when you intended to just have two samples per cycle (the Nyquist rate).  By the way, either sample unit is fine (1 second or 1/Fs second), you just need to be consistent.

Here is my attempt at what I think you intended.

```
A = 2;
Fmax = 10;
Fs = 2*Fmax;
n=0:1/Fs:1;
Cont = A*cos(2*pi*Fmax*n);
Cont1 = A*cos(2*pi*Fmax*(20/18)*n);
subplot(2,1,1)
stem(n,Cont)
subplot(2,1,2)
stem(n,Cont1)
```

I changed the "sin" to "cos" because it was hitting all the sinusoid zero points instead of the peaks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase frequency of the size or use far larger steps in the sampling.

The aliasing does not appears if you have a very smooth function. For example, a constant function does not yield aliasing whatever sampling you use.